# PC restarts instead of shutting down when powered on with WoL

Tags: wake-on-lan

I've recently started using an Android app to trigger wake-on-lan for my Windows 10 desktop PC. I didn't need to configure anything for this to work on the network card, Windows or BIOS. Problem is, if I wake the PC (from a shutdown state) with the app (I've tried multiple apps), when I go to shut it down within Windows, it will start straight back up again. It will then shutdown correctly. Any thoughts on where to begin troubleshooting this?

Comment: Not too sure if this would be relevant but just check if Fast Boot/Fast Startup is enabled in BIOS/UEFI and/or in the Windows 10 Control Panel Power Options. Try disabling this feature at both places and check again. Also what if you use the command line shurdown option say shutdown /s /f ?

Comment: Disabling Fast Boot in Windows was enough to make this work, thanks! If you want to post as an answer I can mark it as the solution.